# Regular expression for password requirement field

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, vb.net

I have a password requirement change box for the users in asp.net.
I am trying to write a regular expression where the four characters of the old passoword should not be same as the four characters of the new password string in C#. The code should return false if they are same.

Can I do this in regular expression.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean 4 consecutive characters?

Comment: I hope you aren't storing the original password in plain text.

Comment: +1 for SLaks. Never, ever, ever store passwords as plain text. Ever. Use a salted hash. Instead of the new password not being able to "be the same as the four characters of the old password" (whatever that means), the new password simply cannot produce the same hash as the old password.

Comment: So you want to prevent `abc123` if the previous password was `dec123`? You shouldn't even be able to check if the new password contains part of the old password. You can check if its the same password, since you still have access to the `current` and `new` password for a window of time, but you should NEVER EVER store both passwords.  What you want is a horrible idea please DO NOT DO THIS.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're trying to solve the [Longest Common Substring Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem). And no, I don't believe a regular expression will easily solve the issue.

This Wikibooks has a C# solution at http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_implementation/Strings/Longest_common_substring.

This seems to be a Java solution, which should pretty easily adapt to C#: http://karussell.wordpress.com/2011/04/14/longest-common-substring-algorithm-in-java/

Edited to note: What the commentators said regarding about storing passwords. You really ought not store passwords at all: rather store a salted cryptographic hash of the password. A non-recoverable password can't be lost, stolen or strayed.

A good initial shot at judging a system's security is to look at whether or not you can recover your password (rather than creating a password). If you can recover it, they're storing your credentials in a way that can be compromised.